# JavaFX MediaPlayer status stuck on PLAYING

Tags: java, javafx

```
public void play(File audioFile, Double startMillisecond, Double stopMillisecond) {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.dispose();
    }
    String bip = audioFile.toURI().toString();
    Media hit = new Media(bip);
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
    if (startMillisecond != null)
        mediaPlayer.setStartTime(Duration.millis(startMillisecond));
    if (stopMillisecond != null)
        mediaPlayer.setStopTime(Duration.millis(stopMillisecond));
    mediaPlayer.play();
}
```

When playing a sound file in a specific duration,
`mediaPlayer.getStatus()` stuck on "PLAYING" forever even after the playback stops at the given StopTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a workaround for this issue using`OnEndOfMedia` Event

```
mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
});
```

now `mediaPlayer.getStatus()` returns "STOPPED" when playback ends.

Answer (score 0):

The following is like Aboud Zakaria's answer, but works when trying to play media more than once:

```java
mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int curCount = mediaPlayer.getCurrentCount();
            int cycCount = mediaPlayer.getCycleCount();
            if (cycCount != MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE && curCount >= cycCount)
                mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
    });
};
```